# Resizing issue in android

Tags: java, android

I have a layout that is displayed in an activity. When i run it on the clique it takes up the whole screen but when i run it on the droid 3 there is a black bar at the bottom and sides. How do i make it so it takes up the whole screen? I thought android was suppose to do that for you?

update:

I am just setting the contentView of the Activity like this:

```
activity.setContentView(R.layout.home);
```

Heres the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/home_screen_lay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/home_screen">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Heres my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".Viewer"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Heres a picture:

[image: Problem]

you can see where it won't resize.

if anyone needs anymore info i can update again.

Comment: It's supposed to do it, at least if you ask nicely. Are you setting your layouts to take the whole screen? Posting your layout code may help.

Comment: Can you post the code you use to define your layout?

Comment: What is `@drawable/home_screen`?

Comment: Does the original background have black bars or is it just a white box?

Comment: @drawable/home_screen is a 569 by 320 background image.

Comment: it is just suppose to be a white box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a problem like this once. It was because the min or target sdk wasn't set to at least level 3 in the AndroidManifest. 
Something like this: `<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="7" />`
I'm guessing level 1 doesn't handle higher pixel screens.

Comment: I didn't have that in my manifest and it actually fixed it, thanks!